# Is there any app for iOS to translate any screen in any app?

Tags: ios, iphone-app, apple

Is there any app for iOS to translate any screen in any app, or any arbitrary screen of the iOS general.

On Android it exists, I have used it before. I don't remember whether I found the feature on Google Translate or on Pleco, on Android that is. If you are unaware of what I am referring to, one could google for something as what goes by the name "Google Tap to Translate".

https://www.cnet.com/news/google-now-on-tap-can-now-translate-text-from-any-app-or-screen/

On apple iOS, it does not exist? Free would be preferred.

Comment: I don't think iOS gives apps that much permission, so no one can do such things except for Apple